# Dynamic logic in systemd service file

Tags: systemd, services

I'm trying to rewrite an `init.d` service file that contains the following code:

```
    if [ ! -r /var/spool/torque/server_priv/serverdb ]; then
            DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS="-t create $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS"
    fi
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS
```

I have rewritten this as follows:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pbs_server
PIDFile=/var/spool/torque/server_priv/server.lock
```

But I have no idea how to represent the `if` in systemd.

Comment: Could you have the server itself do the check, or have a wrapper script to do that check and add the extra options instead of trying to do it in the service file directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's already been said, there is deliberately no support for complex logic in `systemd`. If there is any start-up logic to do (and it isn't part of the daemon itself), it is completely OK to write a small shell script and specify it in `ExecStart=`.

There is one thing to consider, though. The shell script *must not* do any process management by itself. The shell script *must* `exec` the daemon. This is required to avoid interference with systemd's own process watching and management.

An example of a wrong shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -r /var/spool/torque/server_priv/serverdb ]; then
        DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS="-t create $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS"
fi

$DAEMON -- $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS
```

This makes the daemon a child of the shell interpreter. If the daemon does not fork and the readiness protocol (`Type=`) is `simple`, then it's just a redundant process hanging around. Otherwise, if the daemon forks and you set `Type=forking`, then the whole thing will triple-fork, not double-fork, and systemd will kill the daemon.

An example of a correct shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -r /var/spool/torque/server_priv/serverdb ]; then
        DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS="-t create $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS"
fi

exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS
```

This replaces the shell process with the daemon.

Answer (score 5):

You are not going to like this, but it works:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
    if [ ! -r /var/spool/torque/server_priv/serverdb ]; then \
            DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS="-t create $DAEMON_SERVER_OPTS"; \
    fi; \
    exec /usr/sbin/pbs_server -- $DAEMON_SERVER_OPT'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such facility in systemd - because this sort of logic really belongs inside of daemon. However if you can't change the daemon in question you can workaround it by first creating simple unit which will check file existence and create corresponding environment variable and than add "EnvironmentFile=" to your unit. Also add dependency to make sure that your unit is always executed after the one which creates environment variables.