# systemd unit files - conditional arguments

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to convert an old init script into a systemd unit file.

My init script sources a configuration file and depending on some of the variables, some arguments are added to the daemon.

The init script does something similar to this:

```
## My daemon
DAEMON="/usr/bin/my_daemon"

## These arguments are fixed:
DAEMON_ARGS="-a -b -c"

# Called on 'service my_service start'
do_start() {
    ## Source config file
    . /etc/me/config_file

    ## If FOO is defined, add -x $FOO to arguments
    if [ -n "$FOO" ]; then
        DAEMON_ARGS="$DAEMON_ARGS -x $FOO"
    fi

    ## Start the daemon
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
}
```

How can I achieve the same effect with a unit file?

Edit 1:

Here's a skeleton unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
Wants=local-fs.target
Requires=local-fs.target

[Service]
PIDfile=/var/run/daemon.pid
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_daemon -a -b -c

[Install]
RequiredBy=basic.target
WantedBy=basic.target
```

I want to pass the argument `-x $FOO` to the daemon in `ExecStart`, but ONLY if `$FOO` is defined in some configuration file (let's say, /etc/me/config_file).

I know I can read an `EnvironmentFile`, so I could do:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/me/config_file
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_daemon -a -b -c -x $FOO
```

But `FOO` might not be defined, so the `-x` argument will have no value... and an error will happen.

`$FOO` is an option that is read by other services, so it is not viable to make `FOO=-x <value>`.

Comment: I would start by looking at some existing unit file, maybe in `/usr/lib/systemd/system', and the systemd.unit manual page.  From there you might figure it out or at least be able to put together a skeleton of your unit file for everyone to look at and possibly help you out from there.

Comment: I edited my question. I have looked at other unit files. Maybe I missed something, but I didn't see a way to do what I want. And sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly.

Comment: Just put all of your options into `/etc/me/config_file` like `OPTIONS="-a -b -c -x <foo>"` and use `ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_daemon ${OPTIONS}` to start the service.

Comment: I've been fighting this for almost a week now and I can't find any solution other than either hard coding the daemon arguments as suggested by Thomas or just giving up and using a shell script. It seems strange that the relatively common pattern of appending arguments to a variable like `$DAEMON_ARGS` above isn't supported by systemd. A shame really. My first real contact with systemd did not impress me.

Comment: I've been frusted by similar limitations of systemd. My suggestion is to modify `my_daemon` (it is yours, right?) to accept `-x=` or `-x=$FOO` style options, so your service can read `ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_daemon -a -b -c -x=$FOO`.

Comment: I think this is basically the same question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223973/dynamic-logic-in-systemd-service-file